# Reading mixed long and double into same variable

Tags: java, json

I am reading data from an API in Java where the value can be `long` (ex. 0, 3, 45, etc) or `double` (Ex. 0.3, 4.6, 26.8, etc).

The data is coming from JSON and read in as `JSONObject`. Depending on what data is coming in, it gives one error or the other. ie. `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double` or vice versa.

`Double myvariable = (Double) ((JSONObject)parentVariable.get("Index"))`

How do I allow it to accept both types and convert to `double`?

Comment: Strange when you stick on double it should work. Because any integer can also be interpreted as double with zero fraction. Please provide more code, the lines / method where you read the values from JSONObject into your data structur.

Comment: Which `JSONObject` library are you using?  Java has many.  Also, please show the code where you are casting to double.  The code you show casts to JSONObject, not double, and so will never produce the error message indicated.

Comment: You could also try casting to `Number` and then using the relevant method `doubleValue`

Comment: Updated the code to show how data is read in from JSONObject

Comment: @kailanjian sure but the example data is far away from exceading the boundaries of a long or double ;)

Comment: @dsh, I am using https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ for JSONObject

Comment: @ReneM., `Long` class cannot be cast to `Double` class. Only primitive types work. And JSON works with wrapper classes, not primitives.

Comment: @Joel is the capitalization in your error message correct?  There is a big difference between `long` and `Long`, and between `double` and `Double`.  The code you show now will fail if the object is not an instance of `java.lang.Double` or its subclasses.  The `java.lang.Long` wrapper class is not a subclass of the Double wrapper class, but `long` can be cast to `double` (the primitive types).  Also, unless you are missing a left parenthesis, you are casting the JSONObject to Double.

Comment: @dsh he is indeed missing a left parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always use the parent class `Number` and it's method [`doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29).

```
double myvariable = ((Number) (JSONObject)parentVariable.get("Index"))).doubleValue()
```